# get all ids of items in menu group in android

Tags: android

I am dynamically adding the menu items in NavigationDrawer. I want to give unique id to each newly added item. To achieve this I have to check the existing item id's.

So, how to accomplish this? or is there some other way to do this?

layout.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/homes">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/default_home"
        android:title="My Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_home"
        android:title="Add home" />
</group>
```

Activity.java

```
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add(R.id.homes,Menu.NONE,0,"MenuItem2"); // replace Menu.NONE with unique id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to find the menuItem with

```
 MenuItem menuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.UNIQUE_ID);
 if(menuItem == null){
   //Add to navigation drawer
 } else {
   //Generate new UNIQUE_ID and check again if that ID exists or not
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an Arraylist,When you are adding id's dynamically in Navigation Drawer,at that time add that id to arraylist also. When you want to add new id, just iterate through the list and check for that,if it is present not add it and if won't then add it.